# Count the number of times the ID appears, and create a new table with the number of impressions without duplication

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I volunteer as part of my job, and I was asked to arrange an Excel file. In the Excel file I have a long table - containing IDs - I have to count the number of times each ID appears - and then copy each ID along with the number of times it appears.
For example:

[image]

I tried to count how many each ID appears, using the "countif" command. But when I delete the IDs, the countif changes accordingly.

My use of the "countif" command looks like this, I took the entire identity card, and checked for each certificate how many times it appears. The code I wrote is

```
=COUNTIF(C9:C3074,C9)
```

C9 to C3074 - this is my IDs row, C9 - Is a certain ID. I did the operation for "C9" and for each ID separately.

I need to know how many IDs appear, and take each ID once, and together they also took its data from the table. 
for example:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us how you're using the `countif` command?

Comment: Thanks for a note, I will arrange the post right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest IMO to re-arange this table is actually without any formulas. The proces is done through `PowerQuery`.

[image]

Steps:

- Select your range `A1:C7` (including headers)
- `Data` tab > `From Table/Range`
- You have headers, so choose accordingly

PowerQuery should now start, and within the opened tab:

- Within this new pane, select all three columns again
- Got to `Transform` and click `Group By`
- Change 'Header' to your liking and click 'OK'

There should be a new fourth column, exactly how you imagined it.

- Exit `PowerQuery` and `Save` edit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to fix it, I converted all the IDs to the text - and it works